# AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat7, centos7

I'm developing a web app with Java backend in below mention configuration with Loadbalancer ( zen Loadbalancer) environment

APP1 =
Centos 7,
Apache 2.4.6,
Tomcat 7.0.53,
Mod_Ajp connector,

APP2 =
Centos 7,
Apache 2.4.6,
Tomcat 7.0.53,
Mod_Ajp connector,

I'm having the problem after a certain period of time period tomcat JVM not responding apache request
got below error in apache error log ***"(70007)the timeout specified has expired: ah01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header"***

In web browser got ***"An internal server error occurred. Please try again later"***

I verified both the tomcat & Apache servers are running,refer the image

But not responding jvm thread, Which means Mod_ajp connector hanged 
I added following entry in server.xml files. again facing same issue.

" Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->

```
**<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"
 acceptorThreadCount="2" maxThreads="1400" acceptCount="200" minSpareThreads="50" emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false"
 connectionTimeout="180000" redirectPort="8443" />"**
```

My AJP setup

ProxyPreserveHost On

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteRule  ^/$  /index.html  [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydata
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(shibboleth-(sp|idp)|Shibboleth.sso|SAML|server-status)
    ReWriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) ajp://localhost:8009$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "ProxyTimeout" in the httpd.conf in your apache configuration to the same value as the usual "Timeout".